# Scroll-snap-type is not showing at all in my css code, why?

Tags: css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, scroll-snap

i'm new on this forum, and kinda new also in coding... I'm trying to code a very simple page, and I don't know how to select scroll-snap-type, this option doesn't show at all also in the code suggestions in CSS. I would like to apply scroll- snap to the "blocHorizontal" container I made in HTML...so that the div classes inside of it can be scrolled and centered horizontally. I show you what I'm doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Contre-argument:télécharger n'est pas voler</title>
    
    </head>
    <body>
            <marquee><h5>Culture libre</h5></marquee>

        <!-- HEADERS -->
    
        <h2></h2>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="blocHorizontal">
                    <div class="slide one"><img src="gifs/ezgif.com-gif-maker(1)bittles.gif"></div>
                    <div class="slide two"><img src="gifs/ezgif.com-gif-makepr.gif"></div>
                    <div class="slide three"><img src="gifs/ezgif.com-gif-makder.gif"></div>
                    <div class="slide four"><img src="gifs/ezgif.com-gif-makerwww.gif"></div>
                    <div class="slide five"><img src="gifs/ezgif.com-gif-maker(1).gif"></div>
                    <div class="slide six"><img src="gifs/ezgif.com-gif-makerliquid.gif"></div>
                    <div class="slide seven"><img src="gifs/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif"></div>
                </div>  

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
body {
background-color: yellow;
display: flex;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: serif;
}
.slide {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
font-size: 100px;
}
.blocHorizontal {
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
overflow: scroll;
}
.one {
height: 100vh;
background-image: url("../images/gnegne3.jpg");
background-size: 200%;
}
.two {
height: 100vh;
background-image: url("../images/gnegne4.jpg");
background-size: 200%;
}
.three {
height: 100vh;
background-image: url("../images/gnegne5.jpg");
background-size: 200%;
}
.four {
height: 100vh;
background-image: url("../images/gnegne6.jpg");
background-size: 200%;
}
```

Any suggestions???I might have done simple errors, I'm really not an expert in coding fo no Thanks in advance :-)